# Integral of $\int_a^b \frac{\lfloor c \cdot f(x)\rfloor}{c} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f(x)$ be a function of $x$.

Is there a nice way to calulate the following integral: $\int_a^b \frac{\lfloor c \cdot f(x)\rfloor}{c} dx$. Here, $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$, $c \in \mathbb{R}^{>0}$

Given a specific function, I can calculate the integral by manually computing the areas of the rectangles for each piece but it would be nice if there is a general formula for any $f$.

It it helps, $f$ can be assumed to be a polynomial in $x$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, there won't be a "nice way" to calculate this. My recommendation would be to split the integral into sums where $n \le  c \cdot f(x) < n + 1$ .

Then you would get $$\frac{1}{c}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}n \int_{R_n} dx$$

where $R_n$ denotes the region(s) in $a < x < b$ where $n \le  c \cdot f(x) < n + 1$. If $f(x)$ is a polynomial, the bounds on $n$ would be finite, although this may not be the case for general $f(x)$.

Comment: Yes this is pretty much exactly what I was doing. But you need to know $f$ for that. I wanted to see if there was a more general approach. Thanks though; this is helpful